# Xml not parsing string

Tags: xml, node.js, xml-builder, xml2js

I have following string

> "The quic\b\b\b\b\b\bk brown fo\u0007\u0007\u0007\u0007\u0007\u0007\u0007\u0007\u0007\u0007\u0007x... [Beeeep]"

But `xmlBuilder` and  `xml2js` fails to parse this string due to these characters `\b` and `\u0007`. How can allow these characters i also allow `{ allowSurrogateChars: true })` for `xmlBuilder`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\b` and `\0007` aren't surrogate characters. They aren't allowed in XML 1.0 (see "Character Range" in the [XML Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/)). It might be possible to include them in XML 1.1 (See "RestrictedChar" in the [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/)), but I'm not sure how it's supported by the XML Builder.